# Docker build: python package installation fails when connected to wi-fi extender (tp-link)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, docker, wireless-extender

I am attempting to build a Docker image for my Python web server, but I keep receiving the error message `No matching distribution found for <package-name>`. In my case the package I was trying to install was alembic 1.11.1 but as you will see bellow, this is not about a specific package.

**This error only occurs when I am connected to the tp-link wi-fi extender.**

In detail, the error is the following:

```
$ docker build -t test

[+] Building 56.3s (9/10)                                                                                                                                                           
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 354B                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10-alpine                                                                                                          1.6s
 => CACHED [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.10-alpine@sha256:a578a0d69e5df6a9d7af73699553dc80717b2871a24cc9536130a40512b41295                                             3.1s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                              7.5s
 => => transferring context: 3.59kB                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [2/6] WORKDIR /code                                                                                                                                                        4.5s
 => [3/6] COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [4/6] COPY ./alembic.ini /code/alembic.ini                                                                                                                                 0.1s
 => ERROR [5/6] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt                                                                                            46.9s
------                                                                                                                                                                              
 > [5/6] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt:                                                                                                        
#0 9.171 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9a8b718640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again')': /simple/alembic/                                                             
#0 14.68 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9a8b718af0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again')': /simple/alembic/                                                             
#0 20.68 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9a8b718f70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again')': /simple/alembic/
#0 27.69 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9a8b719120>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again')': /simple/alembic/
#0 36.70 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9a8b7193f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again')': /simple/alembic/
#0 41.71 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement alembic==1.11.1 (from versions: none)
#0 41.71 ERROR: No matching distribution found for alembic==1.11.1
------
Dockerfile:8
--------------------
   6 |     COPY ./alembic.ini /code/alembic.ini
   7 |     
   8 | >>> RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt
   9 |     
  10 |     COPY ./app /code/app
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

On the other hand, when Ι am connected directly to the router, running the same command (i.e. `docker build -t test`) builds the image without any issue.

In case this was not a network issue I have tried the following (while connected to the wifi extender):

I specified the platform as `x86_64`, [as suggested in other threads](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/3070#issuecomment-1045133542), but this did not solve the problem. Furthermore, I have also tried [changing the base image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68151915/no-matching-distribution-found-for-tensorflow-cpu-2-3-1-while-building-docker-i) to various other versions, such as `python:3.10-bullseye`, `python:3.10-bookworm`, and `python:3.10-slim`.

I have also tried deleting the specific alembic version but the problem still persisted. Then I tried deleting the whole alembic requirement but then I would get the same error for the next package, meaning that **this is a package-agnostic error**, not being able to install any dependency of my project.

The `Dockerfile`  I am using is this:

```
FROM --platform=x86_64 python:3.10-alpine 
WORKDIR /code
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
COPY ./alembic.ini /code/alembic.ini
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt
COPY ./app /code/app 
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

the `requirements.txt` file is this (I repeat, the packages here do not play any role on error that occurs):

```
alembic==1.11.1
anyio==3.6.2
bcrypt==4.0.1
certifi==2023.5.7
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
dnspython==2.3.0
ecdsa==0.18.0
```

OS and tool versions:

- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64
- Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
- Wi-Fi extender device: TL-WA860RE

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably super late to the issue and you just moved on. But my guess is that your wi-fi extender is either misconfigured or purposefully changing the HTTPS certificates (AKA creating a man-in-the-middle vulnerability) and pip is doing the right thing, not allowing rogue certificates.

Pip uses the system-included ca-certificates by default. [The official image for Alpine Linux uses alpine's ca-certificates.](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/1576b93b13ae6fe75c30ce75583da0c3541f0cb2/3.10/alpine3.19/Dockerfile#L19)

My guess is that if you use a VPN on top of the Wi-fi extender, you'd be able to build without issue. [Sshuttle can easily create a VPN on top of some server you have access to](https://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), if you want to test this.